# Axioms for multiplicative number theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logic, ring-theory

Multiplicative number theory is concerned with divisibility, modular arithmetic and the primes. Of course all of the relevant multiplicative properties are theorems of Peano arithmetic and this is usually the way things are done. But I'm looking for an alternative that has models that are not rings.

In particular, I'm looking for a set of axioms that is satisfied by both natural numbers and supernatural numbers. The latter do not form a ring, since you can't consistently add supernatural numbers.

One more requirement: you should be able to add one optional axiom that forces the structure into a ring. "All factorizations are finite" probably foots the bill, but it seems not that elementary to formulate.

Comment: What is the goal? You can make up definitions any way you want. The question is whether you get nice theorems with those definitions as hypothesis, or if the theorems are what you need for something else. In the supernatural numbers all it matters are the sequence of exponents and how they add under multiplication. If you want, the exponents are a [free commutative monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid#The_free_commutative_monoid), the definition of which could be your axioms.

Comment: Should more, or less, properties of the exponents be kept in this abstraction? Do you need the abstraction to only work with exponents that are in $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$? It is up to you, or your goals.

Comment: Is that all it takes? Just a multiset of primes?!

Comment: At least I know I need a version of the Chinese remainder theorem. 
Can I find a set of axioms that is powerful enough for that, but also allows a model in the supernaturals?
Maybe I should first ask: what's a generalization of the CRT to supernatural numbers?